# A div has some content with bg color. How to make it cover till end of the window.

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<div class="left-pane" style="background-color:red">hello</div>
```

How to make left-pane cover till end of the window.

Comment: `width: 100%`? This question is too vague for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess by "till end of the window" you mean the height of the window? As far as I know, there is no CSS-only way to achieve this when all you have is a single element.

With Javascript (or jQuery in your case), you get the height of the window and set the height of the div to the same value:

```javascript
$('.left-page').css({
  height: $(window).height()
});
```

You'll have to update the height whenever the height of the window changes, e.g. during the `resize` event.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really vague and not easy to understand.

Width / Height of the window/viewport? Try the `vw` / `vh` CSS values when declaring your width/height:

```
.left-pane {
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
   background: red;
}
```

The `100vh` / `100vw` values instruct the div too stretch to 100% of the width / height of the device viewport.